# Avoid extra file when creating tar.gz

Tags: osx, tar

When I tar multiple files up, I end up with an extra file for some reason.

What I am doing is:

```
tar -czvf tests.tar.gz test1.csv test2.csv test3.csv
```

When I look at the tar structure, for some reason I end up with:

```
 tar -tvf tests.tar.gz
-rw-------  1 admin Users 519 Jun  8 11:55 ./._test1.csv
-rw-------  1 admin  Users  52 Jun  8 11:55 test1.csv
-rw-------  1 admin Users 152 May 10 11:09 test2.csv
-rw-------  1 admin Users 152 May 10 11:09 test3.csv
```

I don't want the file `./._test1.csv` . How do I create a tar that doesn't have this?

I am running this in OS X terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an Apple extension for storing extra file metadata.

Set the environment variable `COPYFILE_DISABLE` to turn this behavior off.

Example:

```
$ COPYFILE_DISABLE=1 tar -czvf tests.tar.gz test1.csv test2.csv test3.csv
```

([Source.](https://superuser.com/questions/61185/why-do-i-get-files-like-foo-in-my-tarball-on-os-x))

Answer (score 0):

The file in question is most likely an Apple extension and the reason for the presence of that file is most likely that you are using an Apple specific variant of tar.

You could compile an own tar binary without that "extension"...